# Capture only UDP traffic that cannot be identified as another protocol

Tags: networking, ip, wireshark, udp

I have applied the `udp` filter in order to just capture UDP traffic, as described in [Wireshark Wiki](https://wiki.wireshark.org/User_Datagram_Protocol):

> Show only the UDP based traffic: `udp`

However, this does not only show UDP traffic. It shows UDP traffic and everything that builds on top of UDP.

Since I want to analyze our own UDP traffic only and I have not implemented a dissector yet, I am looking for a way to show only UDP traffic that cannot be identified as any other protocol.

I'd like to avoid adding a list of protocols to exclude, e.g. avoid the long list of other protocols in my filter:

```
udp && !http && !dhcpv6 && !bootp && !smb && !cldap && !mdns && !llmnr
```

**How can I capture only UDP traffic that cannot be identified as another protocol?**

Comment: Why don't you filter the specific UDP port that you're using?

Comment: @grawity: each of our devices uses a different port. It is possible to find out the ports once I find packet of our devices, but I'd like to avoid the extra step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that you're working with Wireshark's *display* filters, separate (and very different) from libpcap's capture filters. (libpcap itself has an `udp` filter, but it only understands very few protocols. So you'll be capturing everything, but filtering the displayed list.)

In Wireshark, the "Frame" section has various metadata about the dissected packet, for example:

```
Protocols in frame: eth:ethertype:ip:udp:dns
```

This corresponds to the `frame.protocols` field. Now apply a *regex* match using `~` or `matches`:

```
udp && frame.protocols ~ ":udp$"
```

This will match all packets where the last recognized protocol was UDP (i.e. `frame.protocols` ends with the text `:udp`). Be careful – some traffic might be mis-detected as some obscure protocol even though it isn't.

(The `udp &&` prefix is an optimization – a protocol match might be more efficient for discarding non-UDP traffic than a string regex match.)

Comment: It seems I need `frame.protocols ~ ":udp:data$"` - maybe that is new in Wireshark 2.0